# Is it fair to promote own posts by either linking them into own Q&A or making insignificant edits?

Tags: discussion, editing, bounty, etiquette

This post is not an attempt to oppose/blame anyone but only to better understand the stance of community.

There are 2 ways to promote own posts:

1. **Link own earlier posts into newer posts just for sake of it**
2. **Make some minor or insignificant edit, which will spam the post on the active question page**

Are these 2 tactics **fair**?

I see that in below posts, the Author mentions own question/answer posted earlier (may be unintended).

[Post-1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/where-do-the-vedas-say-the-vajapeya-yagna-will-make-you-the-next-indra), [Post-2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10658/was-draupadi-reborn-in-adi-shankaracharyas-house), [Post-3](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10645/when-did-garuda-try-to-kill-vishnus-serpent-adiseshan), [Post-4](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10624/do-any-commentators-other-than-adi-shankaracharya-reject-both-pancharatra-and-sh), [Post-5](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10620/does-dirghatamas-ever-call-vishnu-keshava-in-the-vedas), ...

Similarly, in [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/2672/revisions), the spelling "it's" is changed to "it is".

> *Why I am asking this question?*

Below is what I received as a comment from another Stack exchange community my [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/136502/skip-ads-from-youtube):

> It is not a good practice (think of etiquette) to use trivial edits
>   for the purpose of pinging your question on active questions tab. I
>   noticed that you've made multiple trivial edits to your post which
>   could've been avoided. Please use a bounty if your question is not
>   getting addressed or edit when you've an update to make. Thanks!

Actually I was making incremental grammatical changes and alterations to make my own post more readable, but obviously it was considered as an attempt to self-promote my post on active posts, to attract more views/attentions/votes.

So, it seems that in Stack exchange community there is `etiquette` which we all need to adhere to, so that it should not look like a self-promotion. And I want to understand this `etiquette` here in Hinduism SE.

Comment: Pin pointing a person name is not right. Multiple edits can be considered self promotion if the pattern is followed with trivial edits. It matters less, in fast communities like StackOverflow, but in smaller community like Hinduism, it does. "Linking own post" is subjective. That's why it's a personal choice. Here is a related question; which ironically I got it from the post you linked ;-) [Does Stack Exchange have an official stance on users doing a large number of trivial edits to old questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165878/163449). Nevertheless, you raised 2 interesting points.

Comment: I too wanted to avoid naming a person, but then I must give evidence to back my claim...and if I give link, people can see the name of the author, anyways :(

Comment: Is trivial edits exceptable? I don't think so. Edit to old question, acceptable? Why not, till they make improved, even t=minor ones. Mentioning your old post in new answer? Why not , till they are related and make sense and which do make sense in above example.

Comment: @AnkitSharma You may want to post your inputs as an Answer so that others can take a note and follow what is mentioned. After all, You are moderator now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [When should I edit posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you
>   observe.

If any Q&A is quite old then it's not sunk into SE sea forever! In general there is a background process (user) called **[Community ♦](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)**, which keeps poking random & old Q&A at times for attention.

### Linking own Q&A

This should be fine until they make an objective sense with the article in which they are linked. There are no moral grounds for restriction or permission in this regard.
However, the user should understand that such tendency will be noticed if done rigorously and soon people may loose interest in those kind of posts. Again that is subjective.

Comment: Nice answer, given it a good closer.

Answer (score 4):

While it might feel jarring at times, I think it is okay in the larger scheme of things because :-

1. It provides a "repository" inter-related Q&A in one place
2. It does drive traffic to the site.

All said and done, we too have the ability to edit such questions and remove self-promoting references. However, I do not advocate this practice because then the focus shall shift from sharing knowledge to on-upmanship over trivial pursuits. All-around patience ,I think, will keep the SE in good stead.

Comment: sure. this post was an attempt to understand the general view of community and practices followed and agreed here. I guess your answer and one above makes it clear that it is generally OK to link your own post as long as they are relevant and adds value to the post!