# False editing in order to bump the question on active tab

Tags: support, editing

[Note - Referred the [Question-1](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/739/how-can-i-make-a-particular-post-of-interest-to-be-shown-on-the-main-page-of-ac/741#741), [Question-2](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/is-it-fair-to-promote-own-posts-by-either-linking-them-into-own-qa-or-making-in) in order to avoid duplication., I am not asking about linking own post. I am not asking about permission of insignificant edits. I am asking about the misuse of editing privileges]

If there is no any scope for editing/changing anything in question, still asker want to bump the question in active list (in order to get the attention or more views) by making unnecessary changes repeatedly. 
What will be the result of false editing? is false editing prohibited? or any other facility is available to prohibit such false editing?

Comment: Can you give one example what you mean by false editing? Btw, if one doesn't have [edit privileges](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), in order to suggest an edit, there's minimum lenth ctrieta for modification.

Comment: I mean, any unnecessary edits should be avoided in order to get question into main list/get attention. For few sites, after editing, questions are not getting bumped in main list. So asked.

Comment: @Pandya, meaning of false editing - for e.g. in their own question,in order to get attention asker is replacing `it's` with `it is`. And again after some time making same previous changes i.e. from `it is` to `it's`.

Comment: Your question is already answered in the duplicate post. Edit should be significant enough to add value to the post. Personally I would avoid fixing small grammar errors. On lighter note, it looks bit unusual for a relatively very new user to interact in meta so early and that's too with a kind of matured post. Generally such questions are asked by more experienced users (current or *ex-*). Good that you are caring about overall community.

Comment: @iammilind User has experience about SE on other sites. So, it is not surprising to me. New to Hinduism but experienced on Stack Exchange.